# All paths through this function will call itself, runs forever then crashes

Tags: swift

Am I getting this error because I'm using a newer version of Swift than the Apple book I'm studying or am I totally missing something. When I run it, it keeps running hone crashes.

```
func magicEightBall() -> Int {
    let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    print(randomNumber)

    switch magicEightBall() {
    case 1:
        print("You got one!")
    case 2:
        print("You got two!")
    case 3:
        print("You got three!")
    case 4:
        print("You got four!")
    default:
        print("You didn't get anything!")
    }
    return Int.random(in: 0...4)
}

magicEightBall()
```

Comment: You want `switch randomNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You code is recursive function and will get stuck because it will iterate between two lines.

```
func magicEightBall() -> Int {
...
    switch magicEightBall() {
```

And the other lines won't be executed because you called function again before it executes.
If your goal is not building recursive function then replace like this

```
switch(randomInt) {
...
}

return randomInt
```

Comment: Thank you!! I found I had to use randomNumber instead of randomInt as suggested by P Mills.